# docker.service setting for tls connection

Tags: docker, systemd, tls

I'm trying to make TLS connection of docker on ubuntu 22.04.
So, I modified `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` from default.
The modified `docker.service` is below.

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network-online.target docker.socket firewalld.service containerd.service time-set.target
Wants=network-online.target containerd.service
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
#ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

# This line is added to modify docker.service
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --tlsverify true --tlscacert /home/ubuntu/docker-server-tls-certification/ca.pem --tlscert /home/ubuntu/docker-server-tls-certification/server-cert.pem --tlskey /home/ubuntu/docker-server-tls-certification/server-key.pem -H=0.0.0.0:2376 -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375

ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutStartSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always

# Note that StartLimit* options were moved from "Service" to "Unit" in systemd 229.
# Both the old, and new location are accepted by systemd 229 and up, so using the old location
# to make them work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitBurst=3
```

After modifying the `docker.service`, I run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo systemctl restart docker`.
But the `docker.service` could not be active with error.
The result of `sudo systemctl status docker.service` and `sudo journalctl -xeu docker.service` are as follows.
`sudo systemctl status docker.service`

```
× docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-10-21 13:08:45 UTC; 15min ago
TriggeredBy: × docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 11060 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --tlsverify true --tlscacert /home/ubuntu/dock>
   Main PID: 11060 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 100ms

Oct 21 13:08:45 ip-172-26-12-170 systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Oct 21 13:08:45 ip-172-26-12-170 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Oct 21 13:08:45 ip-172-26-12-170 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 21 13:08:45 ip-172-26-12-170 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 21 13:08:45 ip-172-26-12-170 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

`sudo journalctl -xeu docker.service`

```
The job identifier is 8517 and the job result is done.
Oct 21 13:08:45 ip-172-26-12-170 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 21 13:08:45 ip-172-26-12-170 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit docker.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 21 13:08:45 ip-172-26-12-170 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit docker.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit docker.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 8517 and the job result is failed.
```

How do I enable tls and start docker.service successfully?

Docker version 24.0.6, build ed223bc